# How many simple polygons can be made with n points?

Tags: plane-geometry, planar-graphs

You have n points which you can arrange in an infinite 2-D space.  **What is the maximum number of simple n-sided polygons** (i.e. where none of the line segments intersect) **which you can create from any one arrangement of all of these points, by using them as vertices?**

The upper bound, by considering the permutations is $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$.  However, many of these will be self-intersecting polygons, which are excluded.

If n=3, there is by definition only one triangle.

If n=4 then the upper bound is 3, and this can be easily demonstrated by placing a point in the centroid of three points arranged as an equilateral triangle..

I have an example below of n=5, but I am not sure if there are arrangements with more results:

[image]

Comment: The maximum would be over the number of possible direct planar cycles up to a direction given a numbering of vertices, if i am not mistaken for $n=5$ you could take a triangular three points and two inside you make  7 figures, and it is hard to tell if that is maximum

Comment: Thanks @ToniMhax, I have amended my example as per your suggestion

Comment: You missed one: Connect the top center point to each of the points left of center, then complete the pentagon. The result is an approximate reflection of the middle image in the second row.

Comment: Yes 8 you may (not necessarily) migrate this question to mathoverflow because many open problems are close, i don't see an easy argument.

Comment: I may sound very dumb but I am not getting the problem as stated. Why are the length of the sides not taken into account to differenciate the polygons? For n=3 for instance, there are an infinite number of different triangles that can be drawn with 3 points. Or in the pictures you gave, what prevent us to move any of the points a little bit aside to create a completely different n-gone?

Comment: Ok just got it: the points are given and can not be moved. I let my former comment as some others may have missed this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeking a bound on the number of *simple polygonizations*
of an $n$-point set.
This number is somewhere between $4.642^n$ and $56^n$.
In any case, it is $c^n$ for some constant $c$.
There has been quite a bit of work on determining $c$.
A good source is [Erik Demaine's page](https://erikdemaine.org/polygonization/) on this topic.

---

[image: Twangs]


<sup>Figure from Damian, Mirela, Robin Flatland, Joseph O’Rourke, and Suneeta Ramaswami. "Connecting polygonizations via stretches and twangs." *Theory of Computing Systems* 47, no. 3 (2010): 674-695.</sup>

---

Comment: Is there a table of known values for the sequence? I can't find it on oeis.

Comment: @Milten: By "the sequence," I assume you mean the maximum number of polygons realized over all configurations of  points. I don't know if anyone has worked that out.